How to ensure UDF containing api call is being run across multiple worker nodes in Databricks
Working in an Azure Databricks environment.
I have a spark dataframe containing 200 rows, each of which represents a container in ADLS.  For each row I need to sum the size of the blobs in that container.
Function which uses Azure SDK:
def getContainerSize (subsciptId, storageAccName, contName):
    total_size = 0
    try:
        appRegId = "xxx"
        appRegSecret = "xxx"
        tenant_id = "xxx"
        credentialLocal = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=appRegId, client_secret=appRegSecret)
        container_client = ContainerClient(account_url=f"https://{storageAccName}.blob.core.windows.net", container_name=contName, credential=credentialLocal)
        total_size = 0
        blobResponse = container_client.list_blobs()
        for blob in blobResponse:
            total_size += blob.size
        return total_size

containerSizeUDF = udf(getContainerSize, IntegerType())

Pyspark:
containerInfo_df = containerInfo_df \
.withColumn("Size", containerSizeUDF(col("Subscription_Id"),col("Storage_Account_Name"), col("Container_Name"))) 

When I run this on an autoscaled cluster (1 - 6 workers), it appears to only be using 1 worker:
spark job image
I am pretty new to databricks, but I though that using a UDF would ensure that the workload gets scaled accordingly.
I want to ensure that my understanding is correct, and to identify if there is a better way to ensure operations are being parallelized.

can you post value of original containerInfo_df.rdd.getNumPartitions() (i.e. before withColumn() call).

Yes, your containerSizeUDF UDF (user defined functions) is being distributed across the worker(s) in your application during the execution, but be careful with UDFs in spark they are not that performant and work like black-boxes during the execution. Here's a bit of explanation on how UDFs work and some details about autoscaling.

Spark Query Plan: In a nusthell, Spark picks up your code and convert your SQL / Pyspark queries and Dataframes operations and generates an optimized logical plan  (e.g. skip redundant operations, sequence better the order of actions etc.) Then it converts the selected plan to RDDs and divides into job, stages, and tasks. All your code including UDFs are distributed into the shuffle partitions and code.

The problem with the UDFs: Spark cannot optimize them, it's like
a big "eval" in your code and usually python UDFs run row by row of
your dataframe potentially leading to performance issues. Use built-in functions (e.g. pyspark.sql.functions) whenever possible. If UDF is really required, opt for pandas udf given they leverage vectorized operations with apache arrow (tackles the row-by-row constraint).

Autoscaling: it's up to the Cluster Manager decides if more workers are needed - for your case it looks like just 1 worker is enough, so don't worry too much about it.


Improvement Suggestion: Why do you need this API call as column in a DataFrame? If your goal is just distribute the processing and given it's a pure python code, I would rather use multiprocessing or joblib for parallel execution and yield the results in a list. Then, I would use this list as a start point to create a pyspark dataframe, and do the next transformations required.
Examples:
import multiprocessing

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1 # leave one for system interruptions 
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes= num_cores) as pool:
    pool.map(myfunction, parameters)


from joblib import Parallel, delayed

results = Parallel(n_jobs= num_cores)(delayed(myfunction)(item) for item in items_to_process)

Here's a nice documentation for in-depth reference for UDFs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/udf/

Thank you for the information. The end result with the API response needs to be a dataframe, and in researching I found a lot of recommendations to use UDFs in a spark/databricks environment which is why I went that route. Do you have any recommendations for a specific python multiprocessing library that can be utilized in Databricks?

Go for the multiprocessing.Pool or either joblib I added some examples in my main answer @user26590429

Hey @user26590429, were you able to distribute the processing?
